# Can't run cells with jupyter in vs code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

sorry about this vague question, I'm pretty new to the coding community. Till April 2020, I was using vs code with the most updated python interpreter and was able to run the cells using the jupyter feature. When I downloaded python 3.9.0, and used the latest python extension in vs code, I would be getting errors when trying to run the code using jupyter interactively. The errors would be like 'fetching kernel', 'request timed out', 'you need to download the python extension', 'download ipy kernel'.
The reason why I can't reproduce this and show the code is because I finally found a workaround and I'm too scared to mess it up. I had to downgrade the python interpreter to 3.7.9 and also downgrade the python extension to v2020.8.101144. ONLY THEN was I finally able to use the jupyter interactive window.
Is there something wrong on my end, or is this a higher level issue? Again, so sorry for the ambiguity, I'm new to this and I don't want to mess up what I finally got working.